# c++ typedef another class's enum?

Tags: c++, enums, typedef

So here's my problem:

```
struct A
{
    enum A_enum
    {
        E0,
        E1,
        E2
    };
};

struct B
{
    typedef A::A_enum B_enum;
    bool test(B_enum val)
    {
        return (val == E1); // error: "E1" undeclared identifier
    }
};
```

I specifically do not want to say `A::E1`. If I try `B_enum::E1` I receive a warning that it is nonstandard. Is there a good way to do something like this?

Comment: "I specifically do not want to say A::E1" - why not?

Comment: because A is used in several classes and I don't want to refer to an unrelated type. In my actual usage, A is a nested type that is typedefed somewhere else, and it would really be more like N::E::C::A::E1

Comment: Then you will have to make up a namespace and define the enum there. Why not do that?

Comment: Sadly, none of the answers explain how to type it when you can't change the header file where `mySprite` is defined. It comes from a 3rd party. See also [how to define an enumeration inside a class and use it from the outside](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6399081/588306).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon that A should be a namespace instead of a struct.

Comment: Well A has other stuff too, but maybe it would be better to put it in a namespace.

Comment: You can also define an enum at global scope ... or, in a base class that's inherited by the classes which use it.

Answer (score 3):

Putting enum in global scope is too exposed, putting them in a class can introduced undesired dependency. For enum not tightly link to a class, this is what I use:

```
#define CLEANENUMS_BEGIN(name) namespace name { typedef enum {
#define CLEANENUMS_END(name) } internal_ ## name ## _e;} typedef name::internal_ ## name ## _e name ## _e;
```

Then you can use, at global scope:

```
CLEANENUMS_BEGIN(myEnum)
    horizontal,
    vertical,
CLEANENUMS_END(myEnum)
```

That is more or less emulating C# way of handling enums scope. The preprocessor will produce this code:

```
namespace myEnum
{
    enum internal_myEnum_e
    {
        horizontal,
        vertical,
    }
}
typedef internal_myEnum_e myEnum_e;
```

Then a given enum is referenced as

```
myEnum_e val = myEnum::horizontal;
```

Hopefully there's a better way of doing this but so far, that's the only solution I found.

Comment: When C++0x will come...whenever this will be...there will be "enum class MyEnum {... };" that works like the C# enum (with the enum values in an own "namespace"). Indeed the syntax was taken from C++/.CLI (the .NET C++) where it is used to emit .NET enums.

Comment: How do you refer to the elements then?

Comment: you can say EnumName::Enumerator, and can also declare them in somewhere else using a using-declaration like "using EnumName::Enumerator;" to make the visible without prefixing with EnumName:: . this comes with the new underlying type specification, anyway. for "enum class", the default is int. You can change it with "enum class EnumName : IntegerType { ... };" and the same works of course also for unscoped enums "enum EnumName : int { ... }", where there is no default. With that, the possibility of "forward declaring" comes too: "enum EnumName : int;".

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in the past, and this is how I've fixed it.
I wanted to be able to switch the implementation of a library at compile time.
One of the lib was using code like this:

```
namespace Lib1 
{
  enum LibEnum { One, Two, Three };
  [...]
  void someFunc(LibEnum val);
}
```

In my code, I wanted to hide the library implementation from the user experience (so a user of my code should never see what lib I'm using internally):

Solution 1:

```
namespace MyCode 
{
  // Example to avoid copying a function from Lib1 here
  typedef Lib1::someFunc aFunctionImUsing;

  // This doesn't work
  // typedef LibEnum MyEnum; 
  // As such code doesn't compile:
  // aFunctionImUsing(One); // Error unknown identifier One
  // But this did:
  struct Type
  {
     enum MyType { One = Lib1::One, Two = Lib1::Two, Three = Lib1::Three };
  }
  static inline Lib1::LibEnum as(Type::MyType t) { return (Lib1::LibEnum)t; }

  // Now code like this compiles:
  aFunctionImUsing(as(Type::One));
  // This one doesn't:
  // aFunctionImUsing(Type::One); // Can't convert from Type::MyType to Lib1::LibEnum

  [...]
}
```

Solution 2:

```
namespace MyCode 
{
  struct Type
  {
     enum MyType { One = Lib1::One, Two = Lib1::Two, Three = Lib1::Three };
  }

  // If you don't care about polluting your namespace with numerous wrapper 
  // you can write this instead of typedef someFunc:
  static inline void myFunc(Type::MyType t) { return Lib1::someFunc((Lib1::LibEnum)t); }

  // This one does:
  myFunc(Type::One); 
  [...]
}
```

They are 2 issues with the code fragment above. The first issue is that you must copy & paste the enum inside your namespace, (but with a simple regular expression in find&replace, you're done).
The second issue is that your user will have to use the "as" method, which means that it's not straightforward, or you have to wrap the method/function using the second solution.

Anyway, as it's not possible to inject an enum across namespace, this solution is the best you can do. Notice that your code user don't even know you're using the Lib1 library in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I used this solution instead of screwing around with superfluous namespaces.  It keeps the enum safely hidden inside the class and its explicit users.

```
class TreeWindow abstract {
public:
  enum CheckState { On, Off, Partial }
};

class TreeControl abstract {
public:
  class ItemChecked abstract: public TreeWindow { // this is the hack needed
  public:
    using TreeWindow::CheckState;
  };

  void func(ItemChecked::CheckState);
};

TreeControl& tree = ...
tree.func(TreeControl::ItemChecked::Partial);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears there isn't a simple solution. Bothers me too.
If you are allowed to change A there is a solution that doesn't depend on namespaces if inctoduction of the enum to a scope outside A is not desired. In contrast to using namespaces both A and A_Enum can be nested classes.

```
struct A_Enum
{
    enum A_enum
    {
        E0,
        E1,
        E2
    };
};

struct A : public A_Enum
{
    using A_Enum::A_enum;
};

struct B : public::A_Enum
{
    using A_Enum::A_enum; // original enum name
    bool testA(A_enum val) { return (val == E1); }
};
```

EDIT2: removed second solution again, doesn't work as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum ENUM_TYPE
{
  EN1 = 0,
  EN2,
  EN3
} ENUM_TYPE;

struct A 
{
  typedef enum ENUM_TYPE
  {
    EN1 = 0,
    EN2,
    EN3
  } ENUM_TYPE;  
}

struct B 
{
  typedef enum ENUM_TYPE
  {
    EN1 = 0,
    EN2,
    EN3
  } ENUM_TYPE;

  typedef ::ENUM_TYPE G_ENUM_TYPE;
  typedef A::ENUM_TYPE A_ENUM_TYPE;
  
  friend bool operator==(::ENUM_TYPE left, ENUM_TYPE right)
  {
    return left == (::ENUM_TYPE)right;
  }

  friend bool operator==(A::ENUM_TYPE left, ENUM_TYPE right)
  {
    return left == (A::ENUM_TYPE)right;
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Why do you even have the test method in struct B? I don't think it makes any sense.

By defining struct A and defining an enum inside it, you are more or less saying that "here's an enum in scope of struct A" and this is the same as saying "if you want to use this enum, you have to refer to the struct A".

Putting the enum inside a namespace will not solve your problem. Because you will have the same scope problem (C4482)

I think you are making things too complicated. What do you think of this?

```
struct A
{
    enum A_enum
    {
        E0,
        E1,
        E2
    };

    static bool test(A_enum val)
    {
        return (val == E1);
    }
};


int main()
{
    assert(A::test(A::E1));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that A::test() is static. It should be because you aren't operating on the struct state. And since it's static, you dont need an instance of A to call the method.

Comment: It's an example. The real case is more complicated. No, I can't do it that way.