# Where to put the enum in a cpp program?

Tags: c++

I have a program that uses enum types.

```
enum Type{a,b,};


class A
{
 //use Type
};
class B
{
  // also use that Type
};
```

2 class are located in 2 different files.
Should I put the type definition in a headfile or 
in class definition for each class?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902095/c-typedef-another-classs-enum

Comment: Not quite the same question, IMHO.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate.  This question refers to an enum that doesn't belong to any struct, but is used in two classes.  The other question refers to using an enum from one struct in another struct.

Comment: I think it's the same topic: "shall I put the enum declaration in one class and refer to it from the other, or put it in neither and refer to it from both, or maybe put it in a common base class, or ...?". I think they both have the same answer[s] even if they're not both the same original questions.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If the enum is going to be used in more than one .cpp file, you should put it in a header file that will be included by each.  If there's a common header file, you should use that, otherwise you may as well create a new header file for this enum

Answer (score 8):

You should always attempt to limit the scope of types in C++, so the enum should probably be declaread at class scope. The enum will typically belong slightly more naturally in one class than the other - lets say class A, so you put it in the declaration of A in the a.h header:

```
// a.h

class A {
    public:
       enum Type { a, b };
    ...
};
```

Now you need to include a.h in the header that declares B:

```
// b.h
#include "a.h"

class B {
   public:
      void f( A::Type t );     // use the Type enum
   ...
};
```

Comment: It really depends on situation. There's nothing inherently wrong with declaring enum outside of a class, and in many cases this is a preferred solution. Note that you should also attempt to limit the unneeded dependencies.

Comment: There will be a dependancy whether or not it is in a class. Looking at my own code, I don't find any cases where enums are declared outside of a class.

Comment: But there's a difference between a dependency on what you just need (enum) and dependency on the rest of the class A, which is irrelevant and violates the principle of least knowledge.

Comment: Well, we don't know enough about A and B to say anything useful. In my own code, if a class uses a class enum (and all my enums are class enums) it always uses other features of the enum-containing class. But YMMV.

Comment: Without knowing any more, I would say that putting the enum with either A or B creates an unnecessary interface dependence from one to another.  Better to make A and B at the same dependency level (both including a separate header that defines constants, etc), unless there is already an explicit *interface* dependence between the class (as opposed to *implementation* dependencies, which are much easier to deal with).

Answer (score 3):

I can see the point of Neil: it is a pet peeve for many programmers to see stuff on the global scope. otoh, imho, introducing a class just for an enum is not a good style: It is supposed to be enum not a class. However, putting the same enum list in both classes (is what you were asking) would be the worst idea: we don't want to be repeating stuff.

Moreover, in most non-trivial codes, one might end up using more of such shared entities (more enums, const parameters, etc...) for implementation. So, I'd begin lumping all this into an implementation namespace (say "detail") which is a child namespace of your classes, and resides in a separate header file (say "detail.hpp"), included by all. For example:

```
// file A.hpp 
#include "foo/detail.hpp"
namespace foo {
   class A 
   { 
   // accessing enum as detail::a 
   };
}

// file B.hpp
#include "foo/detail.hpp"
namespace foo { class B { ... }; }  

// file foo/detail.hpp
namespace foo { namespace detail {
   enum { a,b, ... }
   const int three = 3;
   // etc...
   // other implementation classes etc...
}}
```

And "detail" is nice and clean way of warning your class users to back off from whatever's declared in there. As your code gets bigger and these implementation details start growing in number you can break the dependencies into separate header files (detail1 detail2 etc...) and still keep one "detail" namespace (something which you can not do with a "class detail" for example).

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather vague, but as a rule of thumb, you should try to minimize the redundancy in your code. Therefore, you should put the declaration of the enum to a header file.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on if the values are the same logical type, or if they just happen to have the same names.  Would it make sense to assign an A::Type variable to a C::Type?  If they are the same logical type, put them in a header that both include.  To keep your build times low you probably want to put it in its own header file, but putting it in a shared header with other stuff works if you want to keep the number of files down.

Another option is to put the enum in a common base class that both inherit from (this may not make sense in this case, but it is another option).