# "error C2065: undeclared identifier" Enum inclusion from another header

Tags: c++, enums, extern

I was building a class in the same header file, thinking it would be small, as my code developed it needed to be put into more than one header/cpp file. My data structure relies in an enum which now is included in another header file. The compiler complains.

error C2653: 'EnumBox' : is not a class or namespace name

error C2065: 'PLAYERNAME' : undeclared identifier

error C2065: 'RANDOMNUMBER' : undeclared identifier

It worked when they were all classes which used my enum were in the same headerfile. What is going on? Extern doesn't seem to work with enums.

GameDataNetworkHelper.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GAMEDATANETWORKHELPER_H
#define GAMEDATANETWORKHELPER_H
#include "../RakNetP2PExample/NetworkHelper.h"
#include "../GameExample/NumberGuesser.h"
#include "BitStream.h"
#include "../RakNetP2PExample/GameData.h"
#include "..\ConsoleApplication1\RandomNumber.h"
#include "..\ConsoleApplication1\PlayerName.h"
class NumberGuesser;
class NetworkHelper;

class EnumBox
{
public:
static const enum GameDataType {GAMEDATA = 0, PLAYERNAME=1, RANDOMNUMBER=2};
};


//..some code which uses RandomNumber, and PlayerName



#endif
```

And RandomNumber.h

```
    #pragma once

    #ifndef RANDOMNUMBER_H
    #define RANDOMNUMBER_H
    #include "../RakNetP2PExample/NetworkHelper.h"
    #include "../GameExample/NumberGuesser.h"
    #include "BitStream.h"
    #include "../RakNetP2PExample/GameData.h"
    #include "GameDataNetworkHelper.h"
    class RandomNumber : public GameData
    {
    public:
    static const int randomNumberType = EnumBox::GameDataType::RANDOMNUMBER;

    //.. some other code
   };


#endif
```

PlayerName.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PLAYERNAME_H
#define PLAYERNAME_H
#include "../RakNetP2PExample/NetworkHelper.h"
#include "../GameExample/NumberGuesser.h"
#include "BitStream.h"
#include "../RakNetP2PExample/GameData.h"
#include "GameDataNetworkHelper.h"
class PlayerName : public GameData
{

public:
    static const int playerNameType = EnumBox::PLAYERNAME;
    //...some other code

};
#endif
```

I've tried also 
extern enum GameDataType {GAMEDATA =0, PLAYERNAME, RANDOMNUMBER};

Comment: Don't make enum static const in class EnumBox. And to use the enum values directly like `EnumBox::RANDOMNUMBER`

Comment: For some reason I did not need to define enum as a data type as shown in my update below. Didn't need a class to wrap the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two headers trying to include each other. Remove any `#include` that you don't need; and try to replace them with forward declarations where possible.

In particular, find a way to stop `GameDataNetworkHelper.h` and `RandomNumber.h` from including each other. Unless `RandomNumber` is doing something really strange, it shouldn't depend on games, data, or networks. Perhaps you could move `EnumBox` into a separate header, so that it only needs to include that.

Comment: No. You can cross include by using include guards and forward declarations.

Comment: @JFGames: Yes, but that doesn't allow a circular dependency, which is what you have here. One will be included before the other, and the other's declarations won't be available there, hence the error.

Comment: Yes it seems so, I added a common.h class and it resolved it as shown above. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It was strange but it didn't like it in the same file as the GamaDataNetworkHelper class.

This post helped immensely:
[Where to put the enum in a cpp program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993505/where-to-put-the-enum-in-a-cpp-program)

Following the above post, I made a common.h class.

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
enum GameDataType {GAMEDATA = 0, PLAYERNAME=1, RANDOMNUMBER=2};
#endif
```

Then updating the two derived types.

```
    class RandomNumber : public GameData
    {
    public:
        static const int randomNumberType = RANDOMNUMBER;
        int randomNumb;
        int maxNumber;

        RandomNumber()
        {
            type = randomNumberType;
        }
        ~RandomNumber()
        {

        }
//... continues
};
```