# how to define an enumeration inside a class and use it from the outside

Tags: c++, class, struct, enumeration

Just because I don't know exactly where to look this up in my c++ book, or on google. How do I actually define some enumerations(in this case `{ left=1, right=2, top=3, bottom=4 }`) inside a class. I want to be able to pass this enumeration as a parameter to member functions instead of an integer, therefore using the enumeration externally...

**Is there a way I can do this, or is there a better way I which I can make the enumeration specific to that class only?**

Here's the code that's not working, saying `enum mySprite::<unamed> myySprite::side member mySprite "mySprite::side" is not a type name` for some reason:

```
class mySprite : public sf::Sprite
{
public:
    enum{left=1, right=2, top=3, bottom=4} side;

    float GetSide(side aSide){
        switch(aSide){
            // do stuff
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Sadly, none of the answers explain how to type it when you can't change the header file where `mySprite` is defined. It comes from a 3rd party. See also [c++ typedef another class's enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/902095/588306)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest change needed to get your code to work is this:

```
class mySprite : public sf::Sprite
{
public:
    enum side{ left=1, right=2, top=3, bottom=4 };

    float GetSide(side aSide)
    {
        switch(aSide)
        {
            // do stuff
            // add breaks; as appropriate
            case left:
            case right:
            case top:
            case bottom:
        }
    }
};
```

You can also do it this way:

```
    typedef enum {left = 1, right, top, bottom} side;
```

Which means define an anonymous enum type for your `mySprite` class and make `side` an alias effectively accomplishing the same thing as the code above. For terseness only the first enum value needs to be assigned a starting integer. All values that come after that point are understood to be incremented by 1 each time unless you explicitly assign it something else.

Comment: +1, at least this one is syntactically correct! (BTW, a third alternative is: `typedef enum side { left=1, right, top, bottom } side;`

Comment: And while that's a third alternative, it's also redundant in C++.  Technically the typedef itself is redundant in C++ (in this case), but it really doesn't matter in the end.  A compiler should be smart enough to understand it either way.  :)

Comment: @david I'm surprised the OP accepted a syntactically incorrect answer. A compliant compiler will just reject that code and give him still more errors to deal with.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune: It is not *exactly* redundant, there is a difference between just the enum name or the typedef. The difference between C and C++ lookup is that after failing to locate a name in the general identifier space, in C++ the user defined types identifier space is checked. If you are interested, I can dig a longer explanation (or locate one in SO)

Comment: No, thank you.  I'm sure you're quite correct.  After all, it makes sense to do exactly what you said.  Thanks for the information.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this example explains it all:

```
class A {
public:
    enum directions { top, left, right, bottom }; // directions is the type
                                                  // of the enum elements

    void f(directions dir) {
        if (dir == left) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
};

A object;
object.f(A::top);
```

Comment: No it doesn't, because the enum is private by default :)

Comment: Ugh, got me there, but HAH you forgot that I forgot a semicolon on the end of the class (it's edited out now).

Comment: And also, since you are using an enum, you probably want to use `switch` instead of `if`.

Comment: Space_C0wb0y: Irrelevant and not important.

Comment: its saying enum mySprite::<unamed> myySprite::side and that member mySprite "mySprite::side" is not a type name...

Comment: alright i posted some more code, the thing being underlined in red is 'side' in the function.

Comment: @nightcracker: the syntax is wrong, you are declaring a single member `directions` of an unnamed enum type in the class. The function `void f( directions );` is incorrect since `directions` is not a type. You probably meant: `enum directions { ... };`

Answer (score -1):

You need to define it as a type to use it outside the class and/or strongly-type the parameter. Otherwise it is simply defined as an `int`, its access modifier must also be public:

```
 
class foo {
public:
    typedef enum DIRECTION {
        LEFT = 1,
        RIGHT,
        TOP,
        BOTTOM,
    };
    void SetDirection(foo::DIRECTION dir) {
        _direction = dir;
    }
    //...
protected:
    //...
private:
    foo::DIRECTION _direction;
    //...
};

int main() {
    //...
    foo bar;
    bar.SetDirection(foo::BOTTOM);
    //...
}
```

Comment: @Casey, it is missing the typedef-ed name, besides being unneeded. You should either use: `enum DIRECTION { ... };` or `typedef enum DIRECTION { ... } XXX;` where `XXX` may be `DIRECTION` or any other name you want to provide, but the typedef syntax *requires* that name.

Comment: @Lutz: I don't know who told you that, but all typedef requires is a type, i.e "enum" and a synonym i.e "DIRECTION { ... }". The "XXX" that you refer to is an optional variable that may be created. If it is not used and left blank as in the example, then no variable is created.

Comment: @Casey: the `XXX` is not the name of an optional variable, but the *typedef-name* (§7.1.3), and it is the new *alias* name for the type. I have checked the code though in three compilers (g++4.2, clang++, and comeau), and two of them *warn* but all accept the code. I have not been able to confirm whether the *typedef-name* is required in the type definition if `typedef` is present, but since it is accepted across compilers it might be optional. Interestingly, the warning is: *warning: typedef **requires** a name*, I would assume that if it is **required** it should be an error if missing

Comment: idk but this code worked for me in msVS++.... will other problems show up or something?